# Output data based on the dropdown list selection

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list in my Excel sheet that contains a series of months `(Jan - 2012, Feb - 2012 etc..)`

I have the drop down working perfectly but say on another sheet. I want the text `Today the month is <insert drop down text>` how would I go about achieving that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Click on that drop down cell

2) Type a name for that cell into the NAME BOX to the left of the formula bar.  Let's name this cell **MyDate**

[image]

3) on your other sheet, use this formula:

**="The month is " & MyDate**

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.. I figured it out :)

What I did was first of all give all months a reference number (so the first month would be 1 then 2 etc..).

Then on  my dropdown liost. I made sure if was referencing the list of months with the reference numbers in the next collumn and then linked it to cell A1 on the same sheet.

This number corresponded to a month listed in the list of months and would change dynamiclly based on the item selected in the drop down list.

I then did a simple VLOOKUP formula that matched the number to the month and... voila!

Here's the vlookup formula I used.

`=VLOOKUP(A1,A3:D14,2,FALSE)`